# What's wrong with lualatex?

Tags: installation, package-management, latex, lua

I'm not sure if this is a bug or I've done something wrong (or I simply don't know `luatex` well enough). This minimal example file `test.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{document}
A random number:
\begin{luacode}
  tex.print(math.random())
\end{luacode}
\end{document}
```

Should compile with `lualatex test.tex` but fails with:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `luacode.sty' not found.
```

It sounds like something was messed up in the installation of `luatex`. They look to be installed:

```
> dpkg --get-selections | grep luatex
luatex                  install
texlive-luatex          install
```

The file exists on my system:

```
> locate luacode.sty 
/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/luacode/luacode.sty
```

so I'm not how to troubleshoot this. Is the package messed up or is it a problem on my end?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The path `/usr/local/texlive`... indicates that you've mixed up Ubuntu packages and TeXLive from source (upstream).

Don't do this.

`lualatex` isn't looking for the file in that location. Install [`texlive-luatex`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/texlive-luatex) now properly (possibly `apt-get install --reinstall`).